# How can I install elementary OS alongside windows 10 without a USB or DVD

Tags: system-installation

Only way of transferring data to and from my laptop is the SD card port, its the only thing that works, none of my usb ports are working and my dvd drive is dead as well. Also i want it alongside Windows 10 as dual boot not on a virtual machine.
Please help!

Comment: Please don't ask questions if you have a broken laptop.Some laptops can boot from SD Card but most can't.You can try installing elementary OS to the SD Card and going to your BIOS / UEFI (you have to use some Windows thingy) boot menu.And how did the DVD drive and USB ports break ? Also if your Windows installation ever breaks your laptop will be useless since you can't reinstall it so I recommend that you fix your laptop or be very careful (don't get viruses , don't download warez (piracy) ,etc) while using Windows and forget elementary OS

Comment: @Abhishek, what model laptop are you using? Many laptops can boot from SD cards, but not all. If you can boot from an SD card then the process is exactly the same as installing to a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite two options in a scenario like this:

1. Remove laptop hard drive and connect to another computer that can boot from USB or DVD, then run installer from there.
2. Install over the network via PXE boot. (requires some sysadmin skills)

Comment: Is there no way to install it through a SD card like people use USB? sorry of that sounds silly, I'm totally new to this. Or maybe something like Unetbootin which is used with Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to consider the SD card boot method. Yes this is option provided your laptop will support booting to SD card devices. Write the Elementary OS installer to the SD card, then see if it will boot.